# unexpected behavior in types

Tags: java

I have just created a simple java program by using datatype `short`.
The program looks like this:

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        short x=1;
        short x_square=x*x;
    }
}
```

This program throws an error:

```
java:6: possible loss of precision
found   : int
required: short
```

How compiler founds `int`? There is no `int` variable in this program all variable are declared as `short`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

During arithmetic operation the integer types are always treated as `int` primitive in Java if none of them is of type `long`. Small integer types are promoted to `int` and the result of the operation is `int`. Hence `x*x` is type casted as `int` and you are trying to assign it to `short`. You need an explicit cast to `short` for this narrowing conversion .

```
short x_square=(short)(x*x);
```

Follow the [JLS 4.2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2)

> If an integer operator other than a shift operator has at least one operand of type long, then the operation is carried out using 64-bit precision, and the result of the numerical operator is of type long. If the other operand is not long, it is first widened (§5.1.5) to type long by numeric promotion (§5.6).
>
> Otherwise, the operation is carried out using 32-bit precision, and the result of the numerical operator is of type int. If either operand is not an int, it is first widened to type int by numeric promotion.

Answer (score 4):

From [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) :

> If an integer operator other than a shift operator has at least one
>   operand of type long, then the operation is carried out using 64-bit
>   precision, and the result of the numerical operator is of type long.
>   If the other operand is not long, it is first widened (§5.1.5) to type
>   long by numeric promotion (§5.6).
>
> Otherwise, the operation is carried out using 32-bit precision, and
>   the result of the numerical operator is of type int. If either operand
>   is not an int, it is first widened to type int by numeric promotion.

Adding a short and a short makes an int. If you want to store the result in a variable of type int, you must cast it.

Answer (score 4):

Because the multiplication of two shorts returns an `int` in java. To get rid of this error you need to have explicit type casting :

```
short x_square=(short)x*x;
```

Or, You can also do the following:

```
short x_square = x; 
x_square *= x_square;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try casting it: `short x_square=(short)(x*x)`